# How to find all possible locations for libraries and header files on any distro?

Tags: linux, libraries, shared-library, distributions, header-file

I found that the location of libraries and header files are very different on different distributions. For Example on Fedora you have `/usr/lib64/libbfd.a` while on Ubuntu you have `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libbfd.a`.
Or on Fedora you have `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-redhat-linux/10/include/stdatomic.h` while on Ubuntu you have `/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/include/stdatomic.h`

Is there a way to know in which locations you have to look without maintaining a list of locations for every distribution?

Answer (score 1):

You can [ask the C pre-processor](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Search-Path.html) (at least, for anything driven by the GCC frontend):

```
$ cpp -v /dev/null -o /dev/null
...
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/include
 /usr/local/include
 /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu
 /usr/include
End of search list.
COMPILER_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/
LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/../../../x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/../../../../lib/:/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:/usr/lib/../lib/:/usr/lib/gcc/x86_64-linux-gnu/10/../../../:/lib/:/usr/lib/
COLLECT_GCC_OPTIONS='-E' '-v' '-o' '/dev/null' '-mtune=generic' '-march=x86-64'
```

This gives both the header search path (the entries between “#include <...> search starts here:” and “End of search list.”), and the library search path (the value given for `LIBRARY_PATH`).

Some libraries provide `pkg-config` files, you can find those with `pkg-config --cflags` and `pkg-config --libs` (with the name of the library).